# Убрать закрашивание фоновой картинки-ссылки при наведении курсора

Tags: html, css

Проблема в том, что у меня все ссылки выделяются цветом при наведении на них курсора и картинка-ссылка (css) тоже при наведении окрашивается этим цветом. Как это можно исправить?

```
</div><a href="http://domain.ru" id="button1" class="bgbutton">&nbsp;</div></a>
```

Comment: Уберите `&nbsp;` и поправьте верстку.

Comment: жесть... полная потеря тегов)))

Answer (score 1):

добавить класс, например .nobg:

```
<div><a href="http://domain.ru" id="button1" class="bgbutton noimg">&nbsp;</a></div>
```

а в css так:

```
.noimg:hover {background: none}
```

Comment: Большое спасибо! Вы меня выручаете!)